# error PLS-00201: identifier kurtwb must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am executing one PL/SQL program but i am getting the error PLS-00201: identifier 'KURTWB' must be declared

```
DECLARE
create_user dba_users%ROWTYPE;
model_id varchar2(20);
user_name varchar2(20);
BEGIN
model_id:=&model_id;
user_name:=&user_name;
Select * INTO create_user from dba_users where username=model_id;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create user user_name identified by password
user_name default tablespace create_user.default_tablespace
temporary tablespace create_user.temporary_tablespace profile
create_user.profile;';
END;
/
```

Below is the value entered by me

```
Enter value for model_id: kurtwb
old   6: model_id:=&model_id;
new   6: model_id:=kurtwb;
Enter value for user_name: rohit
old   7: user_name:=&user_name;
new   7: user_name:=rohit;
```

Below is the error that i am getting

```
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-06550: line 6, column 11:
PLS-00201: identifier 'KURTWB' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 7, column 12:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ROHIT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have entered `kurtwb`as a value of the substitution variable named `&model_id`.
SQLPLus (or Oracle-SQL-Developer`) substitutes this variable in this line:

```
BEGIN
  model_id:=&model_id;
  ....
  ....
```

with the entered value `kurtwb`. After the substitution the code looks like this:

```
BEGIN
  model_id:=kurtwb;
  ....
  ....
```

since `kurtwb` is not defined anywhere, you get `PLS-00201: identifier 'KURTWB' must be declared` error.

---

I guess you want to store `kurtwb` as a string in `model_id` variable, in this case you must use apostropher aroud the substitution variables:

```
BEGIN
  model_id:='&model_id';
  ....
  ....
```

Comment: I guess the error is `identifier 'ROHIT' must be declared` :) Well, the anwer is exactly the same, exept that you must replace `model_id:=&model_id;` with `user_name:=&user_name;` in the answer.

Comment: hi krokodilko

thanks for your response. by the method given by you the above issue is resolved. but now getting a new error  in the line

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create user '|| user_name || ' 
    identified by '||user_name||' default tablespace '
    ||create_user.default_tablespace||' temporary tablespace '
    ||create_user.temporary_tablespace||' profile '
    ||create_user.profile||';';
    END;
    /

    DECLARE
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-00911: invalid character
    ORA-06512: at line 12

Comment: hi Krokodilko I have made the changes
model_id := '&model_id' ;
user_name := '&user_name' ;
then also I am getting the error